# To load from external source to snowflake which tool is required?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

To load from external source to snowflake which tool is required? can you please me know tools?

Answer (score 0):

you can create external stage then table and access that to load into internal table, or you can use copy into as below

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html

you need to create storage integration and use that